# How to fix undefined File() class and its methods in Dart?

Tags: dart

I want to save files in local storage of Android/iOS. I followed the Flutter cookbook to save files but it didn't work. There are examples everywhere using the File class, but it's undefined when I use it. I'm using Dart 2.2.0 and Flutter 1.2.1

I've tried example code snippets from a few websites. Nothing worked. File class, `readAsString`, and `writeAsString` are undefined in my Dart file.

Here's the code. Checked it in DartPad. Where am I wrong?

```
//packages
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

//start
class File {
  /// Directory Path
  /// Local Directory Path
  Future<String> get _localPath async {
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    // For your reference print the AppDoc directory
    print(directory.path);
    return directory.path;
  }
  /// Reference for file Location
  Future<File> get _localFile async {
    final path = await _localPath;
    final address = '$path/data.txt';
    return File(address);
  }
  /// Presenting different Data as 1 String
  String convertingtoString(String title, String author, String content) {
    return '$title\n$author\n\n$content';
  }
  /// Write to file
  /// Writing as String
  Future<File> writeContent(String matter) async {
    /// Get matter converted to string as matter
    final file = await _localFile;
    // Write the file
    return file.writeAsString(matter);
  }
  /// Read from file
  Future<String> readcontent() async {
    try {
      final file = await _localFile;
      // Read the file
      String contents = await file.readAsString();
      return contents;
    } catch (e) {
      // If there is an error reading, return a default String
      return 'Error, Couldn\'t read file';
    }
  }
}
```

This is code from my android flutter project. I get the same errors like DartPad in VScode

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've created your own class named `File`, so that hides the `File` class from `dart:io`.  Name your custom class something else, or do:

`import 'dart:io' as io;`

and use `io.File` where you intend to use `dart:io`'s `File` class. (I recommend renaming your custom class to avoid confusion.)

---

### Original answer

Since you have `import 'dart:io';`, the `File` class should be available to you.

If you're trying this solely with DartPad, then it (among other things) won't work there because [`dart:io` is meant to be used with a Dart VM](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.2.0/dart-io/dart-io-library.html). `dart:io` won't work in a browser, which has a sandboxed environment and generally prevents filesystem access:

> **Important:** Browser-based applications can't use this library. Only servers, command-line scripts, and Flutter mobile apps can import and use dart:io.

Comment: but it's also not working in my android flutter project. I get same errors like Dartpad in VSCode

Comment: @SyedMushaheed After looking at your code more closely, I see the problem.  I've updated my answer.